# Tax question about land sale

Tags: united-states, income-tax, oklahoma

Our home is on 7 1/2 acres.  We are selling 2 1/2 acres of land but keeping 5 acres with our house.  What taxes do we have to pay?

Comment: Tax laws change depending on the jurisdiction. With real estate - both the jurisdiction where *you* are a tax resident, and where the real estate is (if not the same). So, where's that and where are you a tax resident?

Comment: Both in Oklahoma

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you can sell the property under the local zoning laws, and that any mortgage you have will allow this division.

IRS [Publication 523, Selling Your Home](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p523#en_US_2023_publink100073092) discusses selling vacant land.

> **Vacant land next to home.**
>
> You can include the sale of vacant land adjacent to the land on which
> your home sits as part of a sale of your home if ALL of the following
> are true.
>
> - You owned and used the vacant land as part of your home.
> - The sale of the vacant land and the sale of your home occurred within 2 years of each other.
> - Both sales either meet the Eligibility Test or qualify for partial tax benefits, as described earlier.
>
> Also, if your sale of vacant land meets all these requirements, you
> must treat that sale and the sale of your home as a single transaction
> for tax purposes, meaning that you may apply the exclusion only once.

The tricky part is that if you sell the land first and then in another tax year or two sell the house, you will have to amend your tax  form for the land sale year, because there was no primary house sale to link the land sale to when the first return was submitted.

Because you are selling the land this year, unless you also sell the house this year you will have to determine what the gain is for the 2.5 acres you are selling now. You might need to get an appraisal done to determine the original value of the land unless you bought the entire parcel 2.5 acres in a transaction separate from the house and 5 acres.